# Help With 301 Redirection on Plesk Servers (eUk Host Specifically)

Tags: seo, umbraco, http-status-code-301, plesk

I am running around in circles here, I wonder if anyone can help.

I recently moved a static html website to Umbraco.  It is running on a Windows plesk shared plan.

I need to put in place 301 redirects for the old content to the new but:

1. Umbraco won't receive requests for.html, there doesn't appear to be a way to do this.
2. I can't get any server side running in the .html files that the plesk supports as custom error docs.

I was going to use client side meta redirects, but wasn't sure if Google etc will read these right?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but the Umbraco **[301 Moved Permanently project](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/301-moved-permanently)** looks like it does what you need.

The real trick will be piping all requests for .html files through ASP.Net. I'm not sure if this can be done with your web host. But some tips can be found here:
http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/301-moved-permanently/feedback/7271-when-the-old-pages-are-not-from-umbraco

p.s. You are correct that a client-side redirect will not help with SEO.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that project too, the real problem is getting the web hosts to action it.  I am not sure if it is a problem with the host per se, or just getting the sometimes challenged support staff to actually understand what I mean.  They just about get .NET 4 working!

Answer (score 0):

you could add a rule in to your `UrlRewriting.config` the file sits here in the Umbraco installation... "~config/UrlRewriting.config"

The rule would strip the .html extension from the page request. And would look something like the following...
`<add name="removehtml" 
        virtualUrl="^~/(.*).html" 
        rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" 
        destinationUrl="~/$1" 
        ignoreCase="true" />`

You would also have to make sure that the `web.config` file had the following key set to true

`<add key="umbracoUseDirectoryUrls" value="true"/>`

This would allow you to recreate your url structure with nodes inside the umbraco cms without the html or aspx extension. If all this seems too complex you could individually add each page you want to listen for to the corresponding node in the URL Alias property (**umbracoUrlAlias**). Umbraco will take this and redirect to your page.

Comment: Yes, but without access to IIS, the requests for .html never hit the ASP.NET dll, so the above rule never takes place.

Comment: maybe i missed something... what setting would you need to change in the IIS? These web.config should be in the root of your website and UrlRewriting.config should be in the config folder.

Comment: are you hosting in iis6 or iis7?